# Tax settings problem problem

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-class, taxes

so if i sell a product in the uk or eu i must charge vat but my site has all price listed including vat for example

product is on the site for £10, to a uk and eu customer it means they pay £8+£2vat=£10

But currently after doing my tax rules it seems when a customer buys from the US or another non EU country

The products on the site for £10, magento seems to remove the vat and on their checkout page & charge them £8

I want the product to be for sale for £10

if the customer is from a eu country to remove the vat from the product and the total charge exuding shipping to be £10 including vat,

however if the customer is from a non EU country i want them to be charged £10 also and not vat should be implied on their invoice

If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out

just changed the Enable Cross Border Trade, under tax calculation settings in configuration

seems to be working now